# Form input constraints not being enforced?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm new to Tomcat and Spring Web. I'm trying to use Spring's form validation features by following [this tutorial](http://devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring3/mvc/Spring3-login-validation.html). Everything seems to run smoothly except for one thing... my form doesn't do any validation and I can always get to the success page when I send the form no matter which data I provide.

Am I using the constraints correctly? I want to enforce that the user fills in their first name and that the first name be at least two characters long.

```
package net.devmanuals.form;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class RegistrationForm {
    @NotEmpty(message = "You surely have a name, don't you?")
    @Size(min = 2, message = "I'm pretty sure that your name consists of more than one letter.")
    private String firstName;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
}
```

Form code:

```
    <form:form method="post" commandName="regform">
        <p><form:input path="firstName" /> <form:errors path="firstName" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form:form>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegForm(Map model) {
        RegistrationForm regForm = new RegistrationForm();
        model.put("regform", regForm);
        return "regform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateForm(@Valid RegistrationForm regForm, BindingResult result, Map model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "regform";
        }

        model.put("regform", regForm);
        return "regsuccess";
    }
}
```

Am I applying the constraints incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your config?

Comment: Whoops. I tried adding it to my `Dispatcher-servlet.xml`, but I get this error after deployment: *The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.*

Comment: add namespaces for mvc in your config, ie xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your config, you need to make sure the JSR-303 jar is on your classpath.  From the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.html):

> [AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser] ... configures the validator if specified, otherwise defaults to a fresh Validator instance created by the default LocalValidatorFactoryBean *if the JSR-303 API is present on the classpath.*

Comment: After adding `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` to my library list (I already had the Hibernate Validator), everything seems to be running smoothly.